# Using Prompts with scene.slots.params and other parameters

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm reading the documentation article called [Conditions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/conditions).  In that article it describes:

> You can carry out conditional logic in scenes using values from the session.params, user.params, intent.params and scene.slots.params objects.

What I can't seem to find is any documentation on `intent.params` and `scene.slots.params`.  I am guessing what these mean but this article seems to be the only reference to them.

I had assumed that `scene.slots.params` would be the names/values for scene oriented slots.

And now the question ...

If I have filled a scene slot and wish to echo that back to the end user, can I use `$scene.slots.params.[NAME]` in my Prompt value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation on [Storage: Session](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-session#inserting_a_stored_value_in_prompts) and [Storage: User](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user#inserting_a_stored_value_in_prompts) it seems that these are the only two storage areas that can be used in outgoing prompts.